# Creating a button in module control panel to manually perform module action in EE 2

Tags: ee2, control-panel, module, action

I have a module with an action that is in the actions table.
I need to be able to click a button in the module control panel which will perform the action(which usually takes about 15 seconds to complete) and then show a success message on completion. 
I've been through the module tutorial and could not get it working. 
Some help and guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use below code in `mcp` file of your `module` folder.

```
url = BASE .'&'.'C=addons_modules'.'&'.'M=show_module_cp'.'&'.'module=MODULE_NAME'. '&' . 'method='.$method;
$this->EE->cp->set_right_nav(array('Button Title'  => $url));
```